# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException during the Rendering of xml using databinding?

Tags: android, data-binding

I am trying to make custom view using as per the below. And getting NullPinterException. Could anyone please suggest me that how can i solve this issue?

```
public class LabelDetailLabelView extends LinearLayout {

private ViewLabelValueBinding binding;

public LabelDetailLabelView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public LabelDetailLabelView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.labelValueViewStyle);
}

public LabelDetailLabelView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.view_label_value, this, true);

    final TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LabelValueView, defStyle, 0);
    try {
        setLabel(ta.getString(R.styleable.LabelValueView_label));
        setValue(ta.getString(R.styleable.LabelValueView_value));
    } finally {
        ta.recycle();
    }
}

public void setLabel(CharSequence text) {
    binding.label.setText(text);
}

public void setValue(CharSequence text) {
    binding.value.setText(text);
}
}
```

layout xml:

```
 <xxx.xxxx.xxx.LabelDetailLabelView style="@style/SectionContainer" />
```

Error(Stack trace from the IDE) During the rendering of xml

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at au.com.optus.express.views.databinding.ViewLabelValueBinding.<init>(ViewLabelValueBinding.java:24)
at android.databinding.DataBinderMapper.getDataBinder(DataBinderMapper.java:52)
at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bind(DataBindingUtil.java:180)
at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bindToAddedViews(DataBindingUtil.java:305)
at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:118)
at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:88)
at au.com.optus.express.views.LabelValueView.<init>(LabelDetailLabelView.java:29)
at au.com.optus.express.views.LabelValueView.<init>(LabelDetailLabelView.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:458)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:170)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:103)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:168)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:400)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:362)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:652)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:594)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: `ViewHeaderContentBinding.java:26`

Comment: I've mentioned as Error During the rendering of xml?

Comment: The error is happening during inflation. What is on the broken line? (`ViewLabelValueBinding.java:24`)? Also, you will get better type correctness if you use `ViewLabelValueBinding.inflate` instead of `DataBindingUtil.inflate` -- but that is not a problem here.

Comment: It's giving me error in the ViewLabelValueBinding.java      line 24     this.label.setTag(null);

Comment: ViewLabelValueBinding class is autogenerated and it doesn't has ViewLabelValueBinding.inflate function.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? Happening to me too.

Comment: yes, it was issue with the data binding library which now has been resolved in 2.2